# Is $X_i \sim NID(\mu,\sigma^2) $identically distributed?

Tags: normal-distribution

If normally and independently distributed variables $X_i \sim NID(\mu,\sigma^2)$ have the same mean and variance, does this mean they are also identically distributed, as in $X_i~\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2),iid$? ($i=1,2,...,n$)

Comment: Is $NID()$ notation you have seen?  I ask because I have never seen it.  Usually you see it written more like your last bit, i.e., with the $iid$.

Comment: @eSurfsnake So sorry, those are yet more typos on my part... Typed it quickly on my tablet. I really should have checked it carefully before I submitted... Everything should be fixed now.

Comment: Are you (essentially) asking whether two normal distributions with the same mean and variance are identical?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is **YES**, since all normal distributions with the same means and variances are equal.